# Trying to generate a unique ID for book entries in a list but having a bit of trouble

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a unique ID to use as the primary key as well as a foreign key for a list of library ledger data. I just can't crack making a formula that will generate a unique ID while checking for duplicate entries of the book to apply a consistent ID to.

Wondering if anyone could help? Here is the table I'm working on (the authorID column isn't actually a formula and just a hold over from where I got the data from FYI)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use INDEX/MATCH to search for matches and IFERROR to put the next number if not found:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A1,MATCH(B2,$B$1:$B1,0)),MAX($A$1:$A1)+1)
```

Put that in A2 and copy down.